# Finding length and width from depth using factors of a cubic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

So I have this application question:

A pool designer is creating a pool with dimensions of length width and depth that must have specific relationships amongst their scale. Because the design requires input from the customer, the design contains each dimension as a factor of $x$. 
The pool volume is represented by 
$$V(x) = x^3 - 2x^2 - 11x + 12 $$

a) What are factors that represent possible dimension in terms of $x$?

For which I got: $(x-1)(x+3)(x-4)$

b) If the minimum depth of the pool is 1 foot, determine the minimum length and width.

Which I'm not really sure how to do. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you use polynomial division, the factors come out as (x-1), (x+3) and (x-4). Also works if you put the equation into a graphing calculator-the factors are the x-intercepts.

Comment: OK, the polynomial has changed. It used to be $x^2-11x+12$.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your three factors represent length, width, and depth in some order.  Each dimension has to be greater than zero, so the minimum $x$ is $5$.  For that, the dimensions are $1 \times 4 \times 8$.  As the length is conventionally greater than the width, the minimum width is $4$ and the minimum length is $8$.

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you!